# Azure Web service issue

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I recently created a azure app service and using winscp tool  I copied my war file to wwwroot folder and deleted existing html file but still i can see default website my web app not reflecting . please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the /api/wardeploy endpoint using a POST request so that App Service will expand the .WAR file correctly. Using winscp will not work for this. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip#deploy-war-file